# Searching text with 'Match case' and 'Match whole word' in file in C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, search, text

I need a solution in C++ or Java. Are there standard functions?

Answer (score 3):

There are no standard functions to do this in C++ - you need to roll your own. This apparent lack is because the concept of uppercase and lowercase, and indeed of words, is a lot more complicated than it might first seem. Your best bet is to use a regular expression library, such as the one that comes with Boost.

Answer (score 2):

For Java, see [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You can use `\b` and `\B` to match word boundaries. Case sensitivity can be enabled/disabled using the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single function that will do exactly that. It's still fairly trivial for simple cases: get the file in memory (e.g. `std::vector<char> buff(file_begin_iter, file_end_iter);`) and then find what you want. (`std::search`)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use regular expressions in

```
std::tr1::regex
```

if your compiler is up to date. Regular expressions support match case by default. Using \b Word boundaries you should be able to find whole words only.

Comment: Note there is no requirement that a compiler support TR1. A compiler may be "up to date" without doing so.

Comment: You are right writing it "may". In many cases no TR1 implementation is installed with older compilers.

Answer (score 0):

In java:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

You can use the "\b" word boundary.

P.S.: when you compile it remeber scape the slash:
In ex.: To found the word 'dog' --> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\bdog\b");